# How do I properly patch a 3/4" hole in a kitchen ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, patching-drywall

We had a mishap this evening and a hole was drilled through my kitchen ceiling.  What is proper procedure/protocol to patch this hole?  We were drilling down from 2nd floor to 1st floor and the measurements were off, which led to this. It is ¾" in diameter.

How would I properly patch this hole?

[image: Hole]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a setting-type compound (like Easysand 45) for this. Premix compound will take a long time to dry and will shrink quite a bit. Mix to a consistency of thick peanut butter.

I'd also try to not disturb the surrounding area, filling only the hole itself as deeply as possible. Finish by dabbing compound on the patch with a small paintbrush or the corner of a rag to replicate the nearby texture. The smaller the patch, the less noticeable it will be.

If you don't have touchup paint on hand, flat white from a spray can may work. Test on a scrap of cardboard to check the match.

Answer (score 0):

I would use common [spackling](http://www.dap.com/products/patch-repair/spackling/) or [joint compound](http://www.dap.com/products/patch-repair/joint-compounds/).  It may take a few applications, but that whole isn't big enough that I would mess with anything more complex.

To get more accurately match the existing texture, you may want to sand a small area surrounding the hole and add a bit of texture with your final coat of spackling or joint compound.